# How to search vertical table with where clause using mysql

Tags: mysql

I need your help, I am new to work with vertical table, I am looking Now to search the table using the WHERE clause 
when field=1 for certain value.

the result is unexpected the fields returns with NULL value, to look for the result in this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d667/2)

Here is the code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable 
(`userid` varchar(100), `field` varchar(200), `data` varchar(100));

INSERT INTO yourtable
(`userid`, `field`, `data`)
VALUES
('1', '4', 'Blank'),
('2', '4', 'Blank'),
('1', '1', 'Amani'),
('1', '2', 'Engineering'),
('1', '3', 'Cairo'),
('2', '1', 'Adel'),
('2', '2', 'Engineering'),
('2', '3', 'Cairo');
```

the query which gives unexpected result

```
select
userid,
MAX(CASE WHEN field=1 THEN data ELSE NULL END) AS Name,
MAX(CASE WHEN field=2 THEN data ELSE NULL END) AS Faculty,
MAX(CASE WHEN field=3 THEN data ELSE NULL END) AS University,
MAX(CASE WHEN field=4 THEN data ELSE NULL END) AS Place_Status
FROM yourtable
WHERE data='Amani'
GROUP BY userid;
```

I am sure you can know why this happen, and please if there is any other way to achieve the search without using the where clause is welcomed

Comment: `WHERE data='Amani'` will only return you ONE ROW

Comment: thanks @devpro for your replay, but I need the Where clause to filter the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your query as this:

```
select
  userid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field=1 THEN data END) AS Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field=2 THEN data END) AS Faculty,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field=3 THEN datL END) AS University,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field=4 THEN data END) AS Place_Status
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  userid IN (SELECT userid from yourtable where data='Amani')
GROUP BY userid;
```

your query will return all null values because of the where clause - only the following row will be selected:

```
('1', '1', 'Amani')
```